# I am getting error while creating global variable for SharedPreferences in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to create a global variable for SharedPreferences but it throws an error and offers nothing as a suggestion. what should I do?
This error does not happen in other widgets for example when I define button or edittext nothing happens only (as far as I know) in sharedprefences

[image]

```
class SharedPreferences : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preferences)

        sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("MAIN_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)


        var pref=this.getSharedPreferences("MAIN_DATA_2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add you code in code blocks not in screenshots.

Comment: already exists.. please look carefully.. also problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm skeptical it doesn't provide an error message. You can hover your cursor over the error and the IDE always explains what the error is.

Your problem is that you named your class SharedPreferences, the exact same name as the Android SharedPreferences class. Since your class is closer in scope than the Android one since this code is inside your class, when you define your property as a SharedPreferences, it's referring to this class, not the Android one. So `Activity.getSharedPreferences()` is not returning the kind of SharedPreferences that it expects.

Simple solution is to rename your class. By convention an Activity should have the word "Activity" as the last word in its name anyway.

Second solution (FYI only, since you should avoid creating confusing names like this) would be to be explicit about the type you want your SharedPreferences property to be:

```
lateinit var sharedPreferences: android.content.SharedPreferences
```

Third solution would be to create a type alias for the Android type so you can use a different name for it. For example:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences as AndroidPreferences

//...

lateinit var sharedPreferences: AndroidPreferences
```

Side note, that is not a *global* variable. It's a class property. A global variable would be a property defined outside any class.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAGGp.png

Comment: your solutions worked. but I don't understand why it didn't give a warning, thank you anyway.. if I encounter such a thing again, I will look at the import feature first.

Comment: That's the error help menu that pops up if you *click* your bad code. *Hover* your cursor over the bad code or the red mark in the right gutter to see the error message. By the way, it is expected to checkmark answers that solved your problem so your question is marked as resolved and can be helpful to others in the future. You have an unusually high number of unresolved questions.